# Calculating the product of two columns from each row and generate sum result total using Microsoft SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for something nice and sweet that will enable me to take the product of two columns per row and then take each of these products and sum them together for a final total.

The solution must be compatible with MS SQL 2008/2012.

Example of table.

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|         Qty         |       Price      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          12         |       34.25      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          44         |       11.05      |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

The result of this table should be calculated like this:

Row 1: 
12 * 34.25 = 411

Row 2:
44 * 11.05 = 486.20

FINAL CALCULATED RESULT:
897.20

Thank you,

Comment: `select sum(qty*price) from table`

Comment: select qty*price as Product, sum(qty*price) as ProductSum from table

Comment: ok that was easy. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

First multiply each quantity with their price.

```
SELECT
    T.*,
    TotalByRow = Quantity * Price
FROM
    YourTable AS T
```

Then do a sum of all the results.

```
SELECT
    Total = SUM(Quantity * Price)
FROM
    YourTable AS T
```

If you need the result by product (or any grouped column) you can add a `GROUP BY` clause (in the previous example, when using an aggregate function such as `SUM()` without a `GROUP BY` then the whole table is considered a group).

```
SELECT
    T.ProductID,
    Total = SUM(Quantity * Price)
FROM
    YourTable AS T
GROUP BY
    T.ProductID
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **`GROUPING SETS`** to get the grand total.

**Query**

```
select [Qty], [Price], sum([Qty] * [Price]) as [Total]
from [your_table_name]
group by grouping sets(([Qty], [Price]), ());
```

Answer (score 0):

i always calculate the entire total in my client, but you can do it in sql too like this :

```
declare @table table (qty int, price decimal(16,2))
insert into @table(qty, price) values (12, 34.25), (44, 11.05)

select qty, 
       price, 
       sum(qty * price) as total
from   @table
group by grouping sets((qty, price), ())
```

The result is this

```
qty   price   total 
---   -----   ----- 
12    34,25   411   
44    11,05   486,2 
              897,2
```

More info on grouping sets here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
  SELECT TOP(1) TOTAL_AMOUNT 
    FROM (
            SELECT QTY
                , PRICE  
                , QTY*PRICE 'AMOUNT'
                , SUM(QTY*PRICE) OVER( ORDER BY  QTY ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING  AND  0  PRECEDING ) 'TOTAL_AMOUNT'
            FROM PRODUCT ) AS GET_SUM
    ORDER BY GET_SUM.TOTAL_AMOUNT DESC

--SECOND SOLUTION: 
  select  SUM(qty*price) 'Amount'from product
```

Comment: Why use window functions, then use TOP(1)?  Why not just use GROUP BY?

Comment: I JUST WANT TO SHARE NEW IDEA. iT WILL INCREAS YOUR SCOPE IF YOU NEED FURTHER COLUMN WITH RESULT. ELSE I HAVE A SIMPLE SOLUTION SEE THIS : select  SUM(qty*price) 'Amount' from product  ALSO ADDED SECOND SOLUTION IN MY ANS.

Comment: why all in capital characters ? It is considered as shouting when you write all in capital

Comment: I Just Want To Share New Idea. It Will Increase Your Scope If You Need Further Column With Result. Else I Have A Simple Solution See This: Select Sum (Qty*Price) 'Amount' From Product Also Added Second Solution in My Ans. Now, hoping your positive remarks